# Structuring tables and joining records based on lowest occurring value

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I need to set up a query that runs reports for sales per sales team. There are three tables involved in the following simplified model.

SQL FIDDLE HERE: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b09b3a/

```
**users_table**
id     name
1      John Doe


**sales_team**
user_id       sales_team             date_joined_team
1             Sales team 1           Jan 1st
1             Sales team 2           Jan 5th
1             Sales team 3           Jan 10th
1             Sales team 2           Jan 15th

**transactions**
user_id        transaction_date  amount
1              Jan 2nd           20.00
1              Jan 3rd           10.00
1              Jan 7th           15.00
1              Jan 11th          13.00
1              Jan 16th          5.00
```

I need to join on the proper sales team on the transactions table, using the user id and lowest possible date_joined team that is greater than transaction_date for each transaction

```
**desired results**
sales_team                date            amount
Sales team 1              Jan 2nd         20.00
Sales team 1              Jan 3rd         10.00
Sales team 2              Jan 7th         15.00
Sales team 3              Jan 11th        13.00
Sales team 2              Jan 16          5.00
```

I'm not asking for the whole query, just some help on how join on data based on the highest date that is less than than some specified date.

Thanks!

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: "**lowest** possible date_joined team that is **greater** than transaction_date" - but your "desired result" looks like "**highest** possible date_joined team that is **lesser** than transaction_date".

Comment: However.. use a correlated subselect with LIMIT 1. A JOIN would be too complex.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel - you are right. Updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
select date, amount, (
    select st.sales_team
    from sales_team st
    where st.user_id = t.user_id
      and st.date_joined_team < t.date
    order by st.date_joined_team desc
    limit 1) as sales_team
from transactions t
```

If you really want the "**lowest** possible date_joined team that is **greater** than transaction_date", change

```
      and st.date_joined_team < t.date
    order by st.date_joined_team desc
```

to

```
      and st.date_joined_team > t.date
    order by st.date_joined_team asc
```

Comment: Would doing this pose a performance concern were there, say, half a million records to return?

Comment: @Ben 500K transactions?

Comment: Yes 500K transactions, grouped by sales team with the amount summed

Comment: @Ben Yes - I'm afraid, that is going to be slow. You need to benchmark it. But it's not because of the method. I couldn't find any efficient solution for this kind of problem in MySQL. The reason is: MySQL is not able to use an index for `st.date_joined_team < t.date` and `order by st.date_joined_team desc` at the same time. The same applies to `select max(st.date_joined_team) .. where st.date_joined_team < ... `

Comment: This may be an amateur question, but if I were to add a where clause to the end of the  query, would that limit the subselect to the rows returned by the main query. I asking in terms of keeping the query as short as possible. see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b09b3a/9

Comment: @Ben Yes. The engine will execute the subquery only for matched rows. But I have to correct my previous comment: The runtime of the subquery depends on the size of the `sales_teams` table. So if it's rather small, the performance might be ok.

Comment: In the following case I am unable to use this solution, as I am working with a column from a joined table ... workhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/45621046/joining-the-highest-occurring-date-record-on-to-a-joined-table-in-mysql?